# ReactJS fetching new data on prop

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

As a preface, I'm still new to React, so I'm still fumbling my way through things.

What I have is a component that fetches data to render an HTML table. So I call my Actions' `fetchData()` (which uses the browser's `fetch()` API) from within `componentWillMount()`, which also has a listener for a Store change. This all works well and good, and I'm able to retrieve and render data.

Now the next step. I want to be able to fetch new data when the component's props is updated. But I'm not exactly sure what the proper way to do so is. So I have a three part question

1. Would the proper place to do my `fetchData()` on new props be in `componentWillReceiveProps()`, after validating that the props did change, of course?
2. My API is rather slow, so it's entirely possible a new prop comes in while a fetch is still running. Is it possible to cancel the old fetch and start a new one, or at least implement logic to ignore the original result and wait for the results from the newer fetch?
3. Related to the above question, is there a way to ensure only one fetch is running at any time besides having something like an `isLoading` boolean in my Action's state (or elsewhere)?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723095/how-to-wait-for-ajax-response-and-only-after-that-render-the-component) looks related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `componentWillReceiveProps` is the proper place to do that.

Regarding point 2 and 3:

The idea of cancelling the task and maintaining 'one fetch running' seems to be inadequate. I don't think this kind of solution should be used in any system because implementation would limit an efficiency of your app by design.

> Is it possible to cancel the old fetch and start a new one, or at least implement logic to ignore the original result and wait for the results from the newer fetch?

Why don't you let a 'newer fetch' response override an 'old fetch' response?

If you really want to avoid displaying the old response you can implement it simply using a counter of all fetchData calls. You can implement it in this way:

```
var ApiClient = {
    processing: 0,
    fetchData: function(){
        processing++
        return yourLibForHTTPCall.get('http://endpoint').then(function (response)){
            processing--
            return response
        }
    },
    isIdle: function(){
        return processing == 0
    }   
}
```

and the place where you actually make a call:

```
apiClient.fetchData(function(response){
    if(apiClient.isIdle()){
        this.setState({
      })
    }
}
```

I hope `yourLibForHTTPCall.get` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in your case.