# How to update state array without refresh and handling with API requests React way?

Tags: api, reactjs

I have a simple React App that can GET and POST data to an API. Call it a simple todo app. I am trying to figure out the best way to handle the data the "react" way.

I read in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723095/how-to-wait-for-ajax-response-and-only-after-that-render-the-component) that the best place to put ajax call is inside either `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`, however in my app, I can't make it seamlessly reload the data if I use componentWillMount or componentDidMount. I have to refresh the page to see the new addition displayed. Let me explain what I have:

```
  ...
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      todo: 'do this!'
    };
  ...
  getTodos(){
    Client.getTodos((todos) => {
      this.setState({todos})
    });
  };
  postTodo(e){
    let todo = this.state.todo;
    Client.postTodo(todo, (todo) => {
      this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.concat([todo])})
    });
  };
  componentDidMount(){this.getTodos()}; //componentWillMount() works gives me similar effect

  render (){
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello from todos!</p>
        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map((t, index) =>
            <li key={index}>{t.description}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
        <AddTodo todo={this.state.todo}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          postTodo={this.postTodo}
        />
      </div>
  ...
//inside AddTodo.js
    ...
    <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.todo} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
    <input type="button" value='submit' onClick={this.props.postTodo} />
```

Whereas `Client.getTodos` and `Client.postTodo` are:

```
function getTodos(cb) {
  return fetch(`api/todos`,  {
      headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(cb);
};

function postTodo(todo, cb){
  return fetch(`api/todos`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      description: todo
    })
  }).then(cb);
};
```

Both Client methods work.

One behavior I am trying to get rid of, is such - let's say this is my current todos:

```
- Todo1
- Todo2
- Todo3
```

When I enter new `todo`, say `Todo4`, it will, right after I press Submit

```
- Todo1
- Todo2
- Todo3
- //shows a new list, but it is empty
```

I need to refresh the page to see `Todo4` on the list. One way that allows me to add `Todo4` without having to refresh the page is to have:

```
  ...
  render(){
    this.getTodos();
    return (
      <div>
      ...
```

Referring back to the SO post [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723095/how-to-wait-for-ajax-response-and-only-after-that-render-the-component), it is not exactly doing ajax request inside componentwillmount or componentdidmount.

This does not feel like the 'react' way of doing things. How can I update my todos list real time (without reloading the page) the right way while dealing with API requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `postTodo` to

```
function postTodo(todo, cb){
  return fetch(`api/todos`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      description: todo
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then(json => cb(json));
};
```

Ideally you should check what the status code is in the response and update only if it succeeds.

```
 function postTodo(todo, successCb, errorCb){
  return fetch(`api/todos`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      description: todo
    })
  }).then(response => {
    let json = response.json();
    // successCode = 201 for create resource
    if (response.status != successCode) {
        json.then(error => {
            errorCb(error);
        })
    } else {
        json.then(json => {
            successCb(json);
        })
    }
});
```