# Fetch data on Async ComponentDidMount before rendering

Tags: reactjs

In my `componentWillMount` function, I have an `async` function `getResults` that fetches data from a server. I want to pass the response from `getResults` to the same component on initial load, but I noticed that my component renders before waiting for the data to come back from `getResults`. How do I make the component wait for the response before having it render? I am using **Redux** to handle my state.

```
async componentWillMount() {
    const response = await getResults(this.props.category)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait for AJAX response and only after that render the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723095/how-to-wait-for-ajax-response-and-only-after-that-render-the-component)

Comment: I want to render state before the component mounts; not after.

Comment: You cannot force the component's render method to wait for your asynchronous request but you can do a conditional render. Read the accepted answer's last part please.

Comment: I was trying to see if there was a around that. Looks like there isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async/Await only makes your code *look* synchronous.

```
async componentWillMount() {
  const response = await getResults(this.props.category)
  this.setState({
    // use response to set your state.
  });
}
```

Set state is what causes the re-render.

You then use the state to determine if you are in a loading state. If so it may be good to show the user. You also want to handle the default data in the first render. Once you retrieve your response you set the data to the second state.

Answer (score 2):

It's idiomatic React to render your component asynchronously. You'll fetch your data, and set your state accordingly... with a new state, your component will re-render. A common practice it to render the component with a spinner, and when the state is set, re-render with the actual data. At the very least, you can render `null` until your async request completes and sets your state.

Answer (score 1):

> componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is
>   called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in
>   this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we
>   recommend using the constructor() instead.
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
>   For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.
>
> This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering.

[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)

You can use `componentDidMount()` and make the rendering conditional and waiting for the result from the `API`, and then render it with the result.